# Create a helper function to call react-query mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, react-query, graphql-codegen

I am using graphql-codegen with react-query to generate mutations like these.

```
const [createLogMutation, {}] = useCreateLogMutation({
  variables: {
    data: {
      logType,
      message,
      task
    }
  }
})
```

I want to create a helper function which handles the logging to database using this function. However, I am not able to use hook inside a plain function. What could be a good way to implement the helper function?

I want a simpler method like `platformlogger.log(type, message, task)` which would do the job. Without a helper function, I would have to call the above mutation everywhere I want to implement the logger.

Comment: this would be done by writing your own "hook"